# Building StackPanel inside StackPanel with GridView component

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-8, stackpanel, hittest

I need to build something like a StackPanel Horizontal inside a StackPanel Vertical that contains many buttons of variable width (but summarized width is fixed).

I did it on my own and it worked very well indeed... but when I try to reply the result with the GridView page generated by VS2012 GroupedView it sucks.

```
<GridView
    x:Name="itemGridView"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    Padding="116,137,40,46"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PalinsestoTemplate}"
    SelectionMode="None"
    IsSwipeEnabled="False"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">

    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>                        
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="10,5,0,0">
                        <Button
                            AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                            Click="Header_Click"
                            Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nome}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,80,0" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </GridView.GroupStyle>
</GridView>
```

Above is my code, but the problem is that the `minimum hitTest area` for each item inside will break the fixed summarized width. How can I resolve this?